# Oauth credentials in Google Admin Console vs Developers Console

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-admin-settings-api

I have a web app that needs to use Oauth 2 to authenticate with Google Apps for Education. I am the admin for the Google domain, as well as the developer, and so I have access to the Admin Console and the Developers Console. Each console has a method for generating an Oauth client ID and secret, and I've done it in both, but I don't know which one to use. I've tried using both of the ID/secret pair, but I keep getting an "unauthorized" error in my app.

If I could at least know for sure I'm using the correct pair, it would help me debug my app.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing), when you create your application, you register it using the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Google then provides information you'll need such as a **client ID** and a **client secret**. I guess you need to use the client ID and secret you got from Developer Console if you'll be using the [Google Classroom API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth). You can also check on this [link](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en).